# How to find the top Word, number of unique words, and find specific words from text files?

Tags: c++

I have three poems in text files. My current code opens these text files and prints out Unique words, Top Word, and Count for 'Specific word.' 
At the moment my top Word is the word most used, whereas I need it to be the very first word of these poems. How might I  go about changing this code to do so?

```
void BagOfWords::addWord(std::string w) {
 w = normalizeWord(w);
  if(count.find(w) == count.end()){
     count[w] = 1;
   } else {
     count[w]++;
  }
}
std::string BagOfWords::getTopWord() {
 string topWord;
 int topCount = 0;
 for (map<string, int>::iterator it = count.begin(); it != count.end(); it++) {
  if (it->second > topCount) {
   topWord = it->first;
   topCount = it->second;
  }
 }
 return topWord;
}
```

Also, I am not sure why my getUniqueWordCount() member function is short on the amount of unique words. A unique word is something that doesn't repeat throughout the text of the poem. Can someone help with this?

```
int BagOfWords::getUniqueWordCount(){
 int uniqueCount = 0;
 for(map<string, int>::iterator it = count.begin(); it != count.end(); it++){
  if(it->second == 1){
   uniqueCount++;
  }
 }
 return uniqueCount;
}
```

Lastly, is there anything wrong with getWordCount? Whether I am to ask for the same specific word twice it is to always return the correct amount. Or if I were to as for "-" as a specific word, it could do so.

```
int BagOfWords::getWordCount(std::string word){
 word = normalizeWord(word);
 if(count.find(word) != count.end()){
  return count[word];
 } else{
   return 0;
 }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated: `map` will initialize the count of a new word to 0, making a lot of  `addWord` unnecessary. `w = normalizeWord(w); count[w]++;` should be sufficient.

Comment: `getUniqueWordCount` looks good to me. I recommend spinning this off to a new question with a [mcve].

Comment: `map` orders the inputs to make searching easier. The original position of the words in the file is lost. You will have to read and store the first word elsewhere.